# what IS the COLOUR OF vs. what COLOUR IS?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I have a beginner's question:

A friend of mine has a shirt. I would like to ask about its colour. What is the correct way to do that?

1. What is the colour of your shirt?
2. What colour is your shirt?

If both variants are possible, could you please explain the differences. Thank you.

Comment: Both variants are possible. No significant differences.

Comment: i’d be more likely to answer 1 with “My shirt is the colour of a cloudless sky” and 2 with, “It’s blue.”. But as @PeterShor says, there’s really not a lot of difference. And what I said is mostly me just being a wiseass.  Number 1 opens the door to that, 2 does not.

Comment: It's the same as *What is the age of your son? / What age is your son?*, or *What is your height? / What height are you?* Generically, *What [attribute] is X?* is equivalent to *What is X's [attribute]?*, where the expected answer is *the value of the specified attribute (as related to / in the context of X)*.

Comment: @Peter Shor If one adds an adverbial to a similar pattern, in what way could a valid question about the colour be put up? For example: "There is a red carpet in the kitchen". Which of the questions can be regarded as acceptable: "What colour is the carpet there in the kitchen?", "What colour is the carpet in the kitchen?" or "What colour carpet is there in the kitchen?". Thank you.